# Why is my second row not placed at the top?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place to rows next to each other. The rows listen and are placed `diplay:inline-block;` but the cell of the second row is not placed properly like you can see in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kznyc780/).

This what I tried:

```
.row{
 width:50px;
 height:auto;
 display:inline-block;
 white-space: nowrap;
 position:relative;
 top:0px;
}
```

but this is not working. Can somebody help me solving this problem?

Comment: Use `vertical-align` on the `row` for default goes to the baseline http://jsfiddle.net/kznyc780/2/

Comment: @DanielPinzon thanks that works. I already thought the solution was simple but not that simple.

Comment: @DanielPinzon - For completeness, I've added your answer as an answer. If you want to post your own, I'll delete mine. Just leave a comment.

Comment: Np @JDB feel free to post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28347805/why-is-my-second-row-not-placed-at-the-top#comment45039797_28347805),

> Use vertical-align on the row for default goes to the baseline http://jsfiddle.net/kznyc780/2

```
.row{
    /* ... */
    vertical-align:top;
    /* ... */
}
```